# Spring Boot reading property which is not present

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a Spring Boot Application where one of the property in *application.properties* file is:

```
pro.perty=no
```

We read this value in a class and print values based on this properties value:

```
@Service
class MyClass {
  private String property;

  public MyClass(@Value("${pro.perty}") String property) {
    this.property = property;
  }

  public void display() {
    if(property.equals("yes")) {
      System.out.println("Today");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Tomorrow");
    }
  }
}
```

value of pro.perty is "no" in the local application property file. But on Pivotal Cloud Foundry(PCF), where it is deployed, I have set the value of this property to "yes". As external property variables (external to jar) have higher priority than inner ones, so it prints "Today". This works fine.

Yesterday mistakenly, I changed the key of property in PCF to "pro_perty=yes" instead of "pro.perty=yes". Now, the code should print "Tomorrow" as it is not getting any key named "pro.perty" in PCF variables. It only has that key in local application properties file where it is set to "no".

However, it is still printing "Today". How is it able to read "pro_perty" when what it expects is "pro.perty"?

Comment: I suppose it's because of relaxed binding in spring, read here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding

Comment: I tried to run it on local system. Changed property in the application.properties to pro_perty=no. Now it is giving exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'pro.perty' in value "${pro.perty}". As per relaxed binding, spring should be able to read it right?

Comment: The name should also be uppercased (if I remember correctly) so `PRO_PERTY`. Regardless the environment and system variables at least support this and that is why it still works (mostly environment variables don't allow a `.` as a separator but allow a `_` instead).